# How to use $group and $cond together in MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection like below.

```
{
    "userId" : "1",
    "feedbackGiven" : true
}
{
    "userId" : "1",
    "feedbackGiven" : false
}
{
    "userId" : "1",
    "feedbackGiven" : true
}
{
    "userId" : "2",
    "feedbackGiven" : false
}
{
    "userId" : "2",
    "feedbackGiven" : true
}
```

I need to group this on **userId** and get two values as count of totalGivenFeedback and count of false feedbackGiven.

I tried below query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
      $group: { _id: "$userId", feedbackGiven: { $push : "$feedbackGiven"} }
}
])
```

This gives results like below.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "feedbackGiven" : [ 
        true, 
        false,
        true
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "feedbackGiven" : [ 
        false,
        true
    ]
}
```

I can get total feedbackGiven and count of false feedbackGiven using above results from my JavaScript code.

But my question, Is there a way to get it using MongoDB query.

I am expecting results like below.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "totalFeedbackGive" : 3,
    "falseFeedbackCount" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "totalFeedbackGive" : 1,
    "falseFeedbackCount" : 1
}
```

Can anyone give me a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fJGs2_l5GSD)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$userId",
    "totalFeedbackGive": { "$sum": 1 },
    "falseFeedbackCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$feedbackGiven", false] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

So you need to use [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator to count the number of documents after applying [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

And second you need to use [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)itionally to count the number of documents for the `falseFeedback` count